# scipy-0.12.0 failing to install on mountain lion using python setup.py install

Tags: scipy

am struggling to install scipy-0.12.0. I have already installed numpy-1.7.1.

I am NOT installing with pip but am installing with python setup.py install

I am using tcsh so have setenv FFLAGS "-ff2c"

and am getting the following errors:

```
Running from scipy source directory.
blas_opt_info:
  FOUND:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']    
lapack_opt_info:
   FOUND:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
umfpack_info:
  libraries umfpack not found in ['/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework /Versions/2.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
/Users/mariepears/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/distutils  /system_info.py:495:     UserWarning: 
    UMFPACK sparse solver (http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/umfpack/)
    not found. Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [umfpack]) or by setting
    the UMFPACK environment variable.
   warnings.warn(self.notfounderror.__doc__)
   NOT AVAILABLE

running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "dfftpack" sources
building library "fftpack" sources
building library "linpack_lite" sources
building library "mach" sources
building library "quadpack" sources
building library "odepack" sources
building library "dop" sources
building library "fitpack" sources
building library "odrpack" sources
building library "minpack" sources
building library "rootfind" sources
building library "superlu_src" sources
building library "arpack_scipy" sources
building library "sc_c_misc" sources
building library "sc_cephes" sources
building library "sc_mach" sources
building library "sc_amos" sources
building library "sc_cdf" sources
building library "sc_specfun" sources
building library "statlib" sources
building extension "scipy.cluster._vq" sources
building extension "scipy.cluster._hierarchy_wrap" sources
building extension "scipy.fftpack._fftpack" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.fftpack.convolve" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.integrate._quadpack" sources
building extension "scipy.integrate._odepack" sources
building extension "scipy.integrate.vode" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.integrate.lsoda" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.integrate._dop" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.interpolate.interpnd" sources
building extension "scipy.interpolate._fitpack" sources
building extension "scipy.interpolate.dfitpack" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy/interpolate/src/dfitpack-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
building extension "scipy.interpolate._interpolate" sources
building extension "scipy.io.matlab.streams" sources
building extension "scipy.io.matlab.mio_utils" sources
building extension "scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils" sources
building extension "scipy.lib.blas.fblas" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy/lib/blas/fblas-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
building extension "scipy.lib.blas.cblas" sources
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy/lib/blas/cblas.pyf' to sources.
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.lib.lapack.flapack" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.lib.lapack.clapack" sources
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy/lib/lapack/clapack.pyf' to sources.
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.lib.lapack.calc_lwork" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.linalg._fblas" sources
 f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy/linalg/_fblas-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
building extension "scipy.linalg._flapack" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy/linalg/_flapack-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
building extension "scipy.linalg._flinalg" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.linalg.calc_lwork" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.odr.__odrpack" sources
building extension "scipy.optimize._minpack" sources
building extension "scipy.optimize._zeros" sources
building extension "scipy.optimize._lbfgsb" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.optimize.moduleTNC" sources
building extension "scipy.optimize._cobyla" sources
 f2py options: []
   adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
   adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.optimize.minpack2" sources
 f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.optimize._slsqp" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.optimize._nnls" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.signal.sigtools" sources
building extension "scipy.signal._spectral" sources
building extension "scipy.signal.spline" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve._iterative" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.sparse.linalg.dsolve._superlu" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.linalg.dsolve.umfpack.__umfpack" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack._arpack" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/_arpack-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
building extension "scipy.sparse.sparsetools._csr" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.sparsetools._csc" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.sparsetools._coo" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.sparsetools._bsr" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.sparsetools._dia" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.sparsetools._csgraph" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.csgraph._shortest_path" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.csgraph._traversal" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.csgraph._min_spanning_tree" sources
building extension "scipy.sparse.csgraph._tools" sources
building extension "scipy.spatial.qhull" sources
building extension "scipy.spatial.ckdtree" sources
building extension "scipy.spatial._distance_wrap" sources
building extension "scipy.special.specfun" sources
f2py options: ['--no-wrap-functions']
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.special._ufuncs" sources
building extension "scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx" sources
building extension "scipy.stats.statlib" sources
f2py options: ['--no-wrap-functions']
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.stats.vonmises_cython" sources
building extension "scipy.stats._rank" sources
building extension "scipy.stats.futil" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
building extension "scipy.stats.mvn" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7' to include_dirs.
  adding 'build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy/stats/mvn-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
building extension "scipy.ndimage._nd_image" sources
building data_files sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_py
copying scipy/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy
copying build/src.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy/__config__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy
running build_clib
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_clib
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/local/bin/gfortran
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_clib
building 'arpack_scipy' library
compiling C sources
C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64  -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

compile options: '-Iscipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC -I/Users/mariepears/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c'
gcc-4.2: scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vecLib.h:43,
             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:20,
             from scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c:2:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:51:23: error: immintrin.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vecLib.h:43,
             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:20,
             from scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c:2:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vceilf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:53: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vfloorf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:54: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vintf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: ‘_MM_FROUND_TRUNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: for each function it appears in.)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vnintf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:56: error: ‘_MM_FROUND_NINT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:56: error: incompatible types in return
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vecLib.h:43,
             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:20,
             from scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c:2:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:51:23: error: immintrin.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vecLib.h:43,
             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:20,
             from scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c:2:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vceilf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:53: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vfloorf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:54: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vintf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: ‘_MM_FROUND_TRUNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: for each function it appears in.)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vnintf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:56: error: ‘_MM_FROUND_NINT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:56: error: incompatible types in return
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/vv/86b4jvnx07559plzpbz14t600000gq/T//ccrTDfH7.out (No such file or directory)
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vecLib.h:43,
             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:20,
             from scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c:2:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:51:23: error: immintrin.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vecLib.h:43,
             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:20,
             from scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c:2:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vceilf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:53: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vfloorf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:54: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vintf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: ‘_MM_FROUND_TRUNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: for each function it appears in.)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vnintf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:56: error: ‘_MM_FROUND_NINT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:56: error: incompatible types in return
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vecLib.h:43,
             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:20,
             from scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c:2:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:51:23: error: immintrin.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vecLib.h:43,
             from /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Headers/Accelerate.h:20,
             from scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c:2:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vceilf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:53: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vfloorf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:54: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vintf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: ‘_MM_FROUND_TRUNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: for each function it appears in.)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:55: error: incompatible types in return
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h: In function ‘vnintf’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:56: error: ‘_MM_FROUND_NINT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vfp.h:56: error: incompatible types in return
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/vv/86b4jvnx07559plzpbz14t600000gq/T//ccrTDfH7.out (No such file or directory)
error: Command "/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Iscipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/SRC -I/Users/mariepears/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/ARPACK/FWRAPPERS/veclib_cabi_c.o" failed with exit status 1
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is there any reason in particular why you chose not to install it with pip? Maybe you're doing something wrong - are you sure you didn't miss any step?
Compare what you've been doing with [this](http://www.abdulqabiz.com/blog/archives/2013/01/30/installing-numpy-and-scipy-on-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/) guide, making sure to follow the steps carefully.

Answer (score 2):

For complex C libraries etc it is easier to use a package manager like [Macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php), [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/), [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). One reason is that the packgers have solved these compile issues,

For scipy you can also use [Enthought](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/compare-subscriptions/)'s python distribution boith free and charged for.

OSX also comes with a version of scipy (although I do not know the version in Mountain Lion)